# Buggy and Slow scrolling when loading TableView images from CoreData

Tags: core-data, uiimage, tableview, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

**Problem :**
The process of loading images to Table View using their Paths that who stored in Core Data DB works fine , but the user experience not going well. The scroll is slow and buggy.

**Importants Notes :**

- For my local DB i use **Core Data**
- Im not saving the image it self in the Core Data , only their path(the image name)
- As for the table view DataSource , i use an array of type Person that contains an ID and Img name(TableView rows equal array.Count).
  -This is the url im getting my Json from (Check it out) - [Json Link](http://roimulia.com/db.php)
- All the object inside the Core Data DB
- As far as i know , i did all the UI Updates in the Main theard
- After each check im reloading the tableview.

This are the steps that being taking in a right sequence :

**Get the data using NSURLSession - DataTask. After that "parsing" it and check if each object(In a for loop) exists in the Core Data DB,and than appending his variables to the TableView datasource array , and reloading the data**

1)

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: dataSourceURL!)
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in

    if error != nil {
        println("error=\(error)")
        return
    }
    if data != nil {
        let datasourceDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary

        var  DataArray =  datasourceDictionary["descisions"] as NSArray

//Convert it to useable array

        for var i = 0 ; i < DataArray.count ; i++ {
            let ID_s = DataArray[i]["ID"]! as Int

//For each Object from the Json array i'm check if he is exisitng in the local DB
            var ConvertetdID = Int32(ID_s)
            let object : Lockdown? =        self.CheckIfObjectExistInDBbyID(ConvertetdID)

//CheckIfExists - if it does , it return an object with the correct values

            if  object != nil  {
                //exists - load file from Core Data
                let imgname = object!.imgPath
                let photoRecord = PhotoRecord(name:"\(ConvertetdID)", url:imgname)
                self.photos.append(photoRecord)

//TableView object array (photos)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())  {
                self.tableView.reloadData()

//After each check reload the tableView   
            }
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Method that checks if he is exists or not in Core Data DB(the method receive the ID and returns object if exists and nil if not :

```
 func CheckIfObjectExistInDBbyID(id : Int32) -> Lockdown? {
        let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
        var request : NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Lockdown")
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %d", id)
        var error : NSError?
        request.fetchLimit = 1
        var count : Int = managedContext.countForFetchRequest(request,error: &error)
        if count == 0 {
           // println("Error : \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            println("Object \(id) Dosent exist in CoreData")

            return nil

        }
        println("Object \(id)  exist in CoreData")


        let result = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as NSArray!
        let lockdown = result.objectAtIndex(0) as Lockdown
        println(lockdown.id)
        return lockdown




    }
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath method**

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCelllet photoDetails = photos[indexPath.row]





  cell.textLabel.text = photoDetails.name as String
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
        var myPathList : NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.CachesDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)

        var myPath = myPathList[0] as String
        myPath = myPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(photoDetails.name).png")
        var image : UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: myPath)!

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            cell.imageView.image = image
        }
    }

return cell
```

**Any suggestions what is the cause of the problem?**

Comment: Not clear how the code you show relates to table scrolling. Unlikely you should be calling `reloadData` inside a loop.

Comment: @Wain i removed it to the end of the loop , still goes slow.. any suggestions?

Comment: I have added cellForRowAtIndexPath method @Wain

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't always load the image from disk, it's slow. Instead, load the image from disk the first time and then store it in a cache (in memory). Check if the image is cached before loading it from disk.

You need to empty the cache if it gets too big or you get a memory warning.

Advanced versions can pre-cache some images for the cells that are just below the current scroll position.

You may be able to use a library for this, perhaps SDWebImage with file URLs (I haven't tried this).

The buggy part is because your async block doesn't check that the cell hasn't been reused before the image is loaded. If it has then the wrong image will appear on the reused cell (until it's replaced by another image). To fix, capture the `indexPath` in the block and get the cell for that `indexPath` once the image is loaded - if the table view returns `nil` then the cell is no longer visible and you don't need to do anything other than cache the image for future use.

Comment: sounds interesting , can you please support an example with my method above? :(

Comment: give it a try, you learn by thinking through and solving the problem ;-)

Comment: tried for the last 3 hours.. no results , i think i found the problem. each time i scroll it re-load it from the local directory , its suppose to be like that?

Comment: Thats why I talk about caching once loaded from disk

Comment: so you mean everytime i load it move it to nscache?

Comment: yes, but that means you only load it once, then after that you get from the cache (only load if the cache is empty for that image)

Comment: I'll try that ,, so in other words the slowleness comes because the load of the image from cache directory?

Comment: Thats so frustrating , i cant find good explanation how to store and get data with NSCache using swfit lol , do you have a good resource?

Comment: No, I don't really write swift at the moment. It doesn't need to be an `NSCache` though, an `NSDictionary` will do just fine with the key as the path and the value as the image

Comment: Wain i really cant understand how saving something locally and than load it is slower than use NSDictionary , FB app save all the data locally , how the hell do they parse it so fast?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75065/discussion-between-wain-and-jackky-white).